# Changing gnome background from kernel module

Tags: c, linux, module, timer, kernel

I'm trying to set a background from a kernel module, but I can't get it work.

What I've already got is:

```
static void change_desktop(unsigned long unused);

static struct timer_list timer = TIMER_INITIALIZER(change_desktop, 0, 0);

static int umh_test( void ) {
    char *argv[] = { "/usr/bin/sudo", "-u", "mmarquez", "/bin/bash", "/home/mmarquez/script.sh", NULL };
    static char *envp[] = {
        "HOME=/home/mmarquez",
        "TERM=linux",
        "PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin",
        NULL
    };
    call_usermodehelper( argv[0], argv, envp, UMH_WAIT_PROC);
    return call_usermodehelper( argv[0], argv, envp, UMH_WAIT_PROC);
}

static void change_desktop(unsigned long unused) {
    umh_test()

    timer.expires = jiffies + 10 * HZ;
    add_timer(&timer);
}

int __init init_module(void) {
    change_desktop(0);
    return 0;
}

void __exit exit_module(void) {
}
```

And the script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
nautilus_pid=$(pgrep -u $LOGNAME -n nautilus)
eval $(tr '\0' '\n' < /proc/$nautilus_pid/environ | grep '^DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=')
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
cp /home/mmarquez/Pictures/logo.png /home/mmarquez/Pictures/bg.png
gconftool-2 --set /desktop/gnome/background/picture_filename --type string /home/mmarquez/Pictures/bg.png
```

The problem is that the computer freezes after a few seconds.

If instead of running the script I print a message using printk(), it works well.  If I don't schedule the script with the timer, but instead I run it repeatedly in a block, it works perfectly. But it also freezes if I run /bin/true instead of /usr/bin/sudo. Replacing the static struct with a non static leaves to the same problem.

I'm using gnome 2 and kernel 2.6.32.37

Comment: Why are you using a kernel module to do this?

Comment: Don't do that this way. Because a kernel can run without any desktop running. If absolutely necessary, change the desktop startup scripts to query the kernel about your module, then change the background.

Comment: @Dave it's a prank on a coworker. Let's say it's an elaborate one.

Comment: @Juan so, get the source for `init, and patch that to run the script periodically; or better actually, move this to init.

Comment: @Dave Good idea! I'll try to do this in init.

Answer (score 4):

Having the kernel call user-space programs should generally be avoided:

- It ties the kernel code to policy decisions, such as the location of various binaries and the options they take.
- It violates the layered structure of the system. In general, the kernel is supposed to serve calls from the user-space, rather than the opposite.
- It can break in unexpected ways if the user-space is in an unforeseen state.

The kernel does support calling user-space programs, though - generally through the [user-mode helper API](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-user-space-apps/index.html). This is generally used for relatively low-level operations that need user-space cooperation, such as power management, or for operations that cannot be reasonably be performed in kernel-space due to its inherent restrictions. That said, it is used very rarely and only after all other alternatives have been exhausted.

You should probably consider these other alternatives first:

- Have a daemon connect to your module through a [Netlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netlink) socket. This method is used widely (e.g. [udev](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev)) due to its familiarity for user-space programmers. There are user-space libraries (e.g. [libnl](http://www.infradead.org/~tgr/libnl/)) that significantly facilitate the creation of programs that use this approach.
- Have a daemon poll a [sysfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysfs) file created and updated by your module.
- Have a daemon communicate with your module through a new device node.
- Have your module send smoke signals by igniting your CPU - just *please* don't call user-space programs directly unless you have no other choice.

There is a [how-to](http://people.ee.ethz.ch/~arkeller/linux/kernel_user_space_howto.html) that describes the most common methods for kernel/user-space communication.

Since you assume a working desktop, having a daemon monitor your kernel module should definitely be doable. As a side bonus, you will be able to move some of your code to the user-space, where the debugging facilities are far more extensive and the development less risky and time-consuming.

**EDIT:**

By the way, `call_usermodehelper()` is supposed to be called from process context. Calling it from a timer does not not fulfill that requirement - your code basically runs in interrupt context.

Comment: +1, doesn't resolve my problem, but helped me to understand many things